# How to get text from textbox to function on click of button

Tags: javascript, html

Well I want to make a small form that when entering the text of "caracas" gives me a series of options.

but I got stuck here in this.

```
let boton=document.getElementById('button');
boton=document.addEventListener('click',funcionDelTexto);

let inputText=document.getElementById('texto').value;

function funcionDelTexto (inputText) {
  switch (inputText) {

      case 'caracas':
      let caracasResult=document.createElement('p');
      let caracasContent=document.createTextNode('Venezuela');
      caracasResult.appendChild(caracasContent);
      
      let insertResult=document.getElementById('parrafoOne');
      document.body.insertBefore(caracasResult,insertResult);
      
      break;
  
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: add more `case:`s

Comment: Move `let inputText=document.getElementById('texto').value;` inside the function because it does not get passed in as argument the way you think it does

Comment: as I said bro I got stuck in how to make the text that I enter in the input is the one that I put in the "switch"

Comment: `function funcionDelTexto (inputText) {
  switch (inputText) {
    
let inputText=document.getElementById('texto').value;
      case 'caracas':
      let caracasResult=document.createElement('p');
      let caracasContent=document.createTextNode('Venezuela');
      caracasResult.appendChild(caracasContent);
      
      let insertResult=document.getElementById('parrafoOne');
      document.body.insertBefore(caracasResult,insertResult);
      
      break;
  
    default:
      break;
  }`

Comment: I've changed the title to be a summary of the question, rather than a general statement about you and your relationship with JavaScript :). If you give a read to [ask], you'll note this is one of the pieces of advice there.

Comment: ahh okay i will from now on actually this in my first post:)

Answer (score -1):

I already solved it, it was such a "stupid" problem but it made my life impossible hahaha.

This could be obvious to some, it was difficult for me.

I just had to remove the "LET" when declaring the variable haha.

[image: ready]